# sum of digit of a large power

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

what is $P(P(P(333^{333})))$, where P is sum of digit of a number. for an example $P(35)=3+5=8$

a)18

b)9

c)33

d)333

f)5

I tried to find this but I couldn't. I started to find a pattern for an example the first few power of $333^{333}$ are:

$A=333*333=110889             \; \; \; \; \; \;    P(A)=3^{3}=27$

$B=110889*333= 36926037      \; \; \; \; \; \;      P(B)=36$

$C=36926037*333=12296370321   \; \; \; \; \; \;     P(C)=36  $

$D=12296370321*333=4094691316893 \; \; \; \; \; \;  P(D)=63$

Can I say it is always 9? so $P(P(P(333^{333})))=9$?

Comment: It has to be a multiple of $9$; that rules out c) and f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$333^{333} $ has $840 $ digits, so the sum of its digits $P(333^{333})$ could be at most $9\times840=7560$.

Since $P(333^{333})$ has at most four digits, $P(P(333^{333}))$ could be at most $9\times4=36$.

Since $P(P(333^{333}))\le36$, $P(P(P(333^{333})))\lt18.$

Also $333^{333}$ is a multiple of $9$, so $P(P(P(333^{333})))$ is.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

$333^{333} < 1000^{333} = 10^{999}$ so our number has less than $1000$ digits in it.

$P(333^{333})$ is then somewhere strictly between $0$ and $1000\cdot 9 = 90000$ since the largest sum would have occurred if we really had $1000$ digits and they were all $9$'s and the sum clearly cannot be zero as the only number with digitsum equal to zero is zero itself.

We then also have $P(P(333^{333}))\leq P(89999) = 44$ since $89999$ is the number with the largest digit sum while the number is still less than or equal to $90000$

Similarly, $P(P(P(333^{333})))\leq P(39) = 12$ since the number with the largest possible sum of digits less than $44$ is $39$.

So...  This all tells us that $P(P(P(333^{333})))\leq 12$

Now... recall that the sum of the digits of a number has the same remainder as the original number when divided by $9$.  Clearly, $333^{333}$ is a multiple of $9$ so $P(P(P(333^{333})))$ must be a multiple of $9$ as well.

As $9$ is the only multiple of nine between $0$ and $12$, it follows that the digit sum is exactly $9$.